# c# console application that opens/runs files/programs based on user inpit

Tags: c#

heads up, I am completely new to coding in c# and I'm still a student in my first year but I was given a project where I need to basically make a c# Console Application (**no windows forms**, **just purely c#**) where it opens a file or runs a program based **on *whatever* the user inputs**. In addition, add a file existence check which would either open the file/run exe if it exists or exit the program if it doesn't. I tried researching for help but didn't get anything specific but here is what I have so far and I'm stuck as for what I need to do next. Any help is appreciated as I am still learning

```
void RUNNER()
{
    // Capture user input
    Console.WriteLine("Enter directory for file/program to run");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    // Check for file existence
    if (File.Exists(userInput))
    {
        File.OpenRead(userInput);
        Console.WriteLine("This file exists, opening...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the user input file self executable?

Comment: No, the user input can be any file on the pc or an exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) and [Process.StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)

```
Process process = Process.Start(userInput)
```

Note: If the file exists in `bin` directory, then you can call it directly, otherwise, you need to call in with `path`

Example:

```
Process process = Process.Start('sample.exe')
```

or

```
Process process = Process.Start(@'c:\dir\sample.exe')
```

Comment: void RUNNER()
{
    // Capture user input
    Console.WriteLine("Enter directory for file/program to run");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    // Check for file existence
    if (File.Exists(userInput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This file exists, opening...");
        Process.Start(userInput);
    }
}

I tried this, but the files I tried didn't open... did I say it incorrectly?